# how to implement dynamic breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to implement dynamic breadcrumb and really dont know how do i go about it. Cant find much examples on internet. Please see attached image where i have added breadcrumb. The code for it as below

```
  <div style="font-size: 10px;">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a> <span class="divider">></span>
            </li>

            <li>

            <li><a id="navObject" href="../AgrProduct/Index.aspx" class="active" >Search</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

[image: breadcrumb]

Currently i have just 2 level in breadcrumb as Home and Search. when i click on button Search it will show me list of products and when i select one on product the breadcrumb should show as Home > Search > Product. I am also attaching image of what happens when i click on Search button

[image: SearchResult]

Please let me know how should i go about it. I am really stuck. I use knockout,jquery.

Comment: Any clue?  I really need to get this sorted

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you created a breadcrumb view model:

```
var breadCrumbViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.breadCrumbs = ko.observableArray();

    self.addCrumb = function(url, text, active)
    {
        self.breadCrumbs.push({ 'url': url, 'text': text, 'active': active });
    }

    self.reset = function()
    {
        self.breadCrumbs.removeAll();
    }
}
```

And then use it something like this (I've not tested this, so there may be some errors in it, but the idea should be good!)

```
 <ul class="breadcrumb" data-bind="foreach: breadCrumbViewModel.breadCrumbs">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: url }, text: text, css: { active: active }"></a> <span data-bind="visible: $index < breadCrumbViewModel.breadCrumbs - 1" class="divider">></span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

You would set it up in the function called whenever you navigate to a "page" within your SPA:

```
function()
{
    breadCrumbViewModel.reset();
    breadCrumbViewModel.addCrumb('#/Home', 'Home');
    breadCrumbViewModel.addCrumb('#/Product/:id', 'Search', true);
}
```

Don't forget to bind the model the the html element for knockout to do its stuff.

I'm using the example code for [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/docs/tutorials/json_store_1) for the navigation, though I will admit that I haven't used sammy.js before, I've got a custom implementation of navhistory.js from the [Microsoft Big Shelf SPA example](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/previous-version/sample-bigshelf-application/big-shelf-code). But that should be enough to give you a head start on it. I'm assuming that you actually want this to be a SPA, despite having actual URLs in your links that would take you off to another page.

Comment: Where will we set the url?

Comment: If its possible to provide fiddle for this then would be too much thankful to you

Comment: Is this a single page app?

Comment: What are you using for history/navigation? If you're firing off a method to navigate for each click, then in that method you need to set the breadcrumbs observable array to the new breadcrumb values for that page view. You'll need to add a method to the view model to clear out the array before populating it again.

Comment: currently  i m using nothing for history/navigation. If you can show small example on fiddle then it would help me really.

Comment: Not got time now to put together a jsfiddle, but updated the answer to provide more code. Try putting it in a jsfiddle, but I won't get a chance to look until later on Sunday, though someone else may be able to help you.

Comment: I am really thankful for your efforts. Even i have not got time to look into this. I will look on monday

Comment: I have still not looked into this and i am sorry about it. I am stuck with few other things. I will come back to you soon for sure when i start implementing it.